# MySql после установки на Centos 7 не запускается

Tags: mysql, centos7

Устанавливаю MySql на Centos7 следующим образом. Сначала скачиваю

```
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql80-community-release-el7-3.noarch.rpm
```

Затем выполняю команду:

```
rpm -Uvh mysql80-community-release-el7-3.noarch.rpm
```

Обновляю список репозиториев

```
yum update
```

После чего выполняю установка mysql сервера

```
yum -y install mysql-server
```

После того, как он установился, я пытаюсь его запустить командой

```
systemctl start mysqld
```

Я получаю такую ошибку:  `Job for mysqld.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered to the control process. See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`
Я проверил лог /var/log/mysqld.log Но в нем ничего нет, кроме строчек

```
2020-01-14T08:39:20.375839Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.19) initializing of server in progress as process 11837
2020-01-14T08:39:40.349406Z 5 [Note] [MY-010454] [Server] A temporary password is generated for user@localhost: пароль
2020-01-14T08:40:33.795735Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.19) initializing of server in progress as process 12067
2020-01-14T08:40:54.140849Z 5 [Note] [MY-010454] [Server] A temporary password is generated for user@localhost: пароль
```

Можете подсказать в чем проблема? Может я, что-то не так делаю?

Команда `journalctl -e -u mysqld.service` выводит следующее:

```
Jan 14 05:56:54   systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
Jan 14 05:56:54   systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
Jan 14 05:56:54   systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.
Jan 14 05:56:55   systemd[1]: mysqld.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jan 14 05:56:55   systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Server.
Jan 14 05:56:55   systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Server...
Jan 14 05:56:56   systemd[1]: mysqld.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Jan 14 05:56:56   systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
Jan 14 05:56:56   systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
Jan 14 05:56:56   systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.
Jan 14 05:56:56   systemd[1]: mysqld.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jan 14 05:56:56   systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Server.
Jan 14 05:56:56   systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Server...
Jan 14 05:56:57   systemd[1]: mysqld.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Jan 14 05:56:57   systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
Jan 14 05:56:57   systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
Jan 14 05:56:57   systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.
Jan 14 05:56:57   systemd[1]: mysqld.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jan 14 05:56:57   systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Server.
Jan 14 05:56:57   systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for mysqld.service
Jan 14 05:56:57   systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
Jan 14 05:56:57   systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
Jan 14 05:56:57   systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.
lines 979-1001/1001 (END)
Jan 14 05:56:54   systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
Jan 14 05:56:54   systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
Jan 14 05:56:54   systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.
Jan 14 05:56:55   systemd[1]: mysqld.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jan 14 05:56:55   systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Server.
Jan 14 05:56:55   systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Server...
Jan 14 05:56:56   systemd[1]: mysqld.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Jan 14 05:56:56   systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
Jan 14 05:56:56   systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
Jan 14 05:56:56   systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.
Jan 14 05:56:56   systemd[1]: mysqld.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jan 14 05:56:56   systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Server.
Jan 14 05:56:56   systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Server...
Jan 14 05:56:57   systemd[1]: mysqld.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Jan 14 05:56:57   systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
Jan 14 05:56:57   systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
Jan 14 05:56:57   systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.
Jan 14 05:56:57   systemd[1]: mysqld.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jan 14 05:56:57   systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Server.
Jan 14 05:56:57   systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for mysqld.service
Jan 14 05:56:57   systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
Jan 14 05:56:57   systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
Jan 14 05:56:57   systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы понять причину посмотри статус

```
systemctl status mysqld.service
```

Comment: Эта команда выдает вот такие результаты: * mysqld.service - MySQL Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Tue 2020-01-14 05:56:57 EST; 15min ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
     http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
  Process: 14990 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS (code=killed, signal=KILL)
  Process: 14961 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 14990 (code=killed, signal=KILL)
   Status: "Server startup in progress"

Comment: systemctl -l status mysqld.service
так попробуй

Comment: Тоже самое и еще выдает: systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.
systemd[1]: mysqld.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Server.
systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for mysqld.service
systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.

Comment: выложи содержимое systemd юнит этого сервиса

Comment: journalctl -e -u mysqld.service

Comment: Добавил в вопросе, что выводит эта команда journalctl -e -u mysqld.service